# Fonts not Rendering Smoothly

Tags: html, css, fonts, compatibility

I'm developing a website using self-hosted fonts. Testing on different browsers and computers, I noticed that the fonts weren't displaying well on any website. I noticed that on my computer, the fonts display well on Chrome, yet on other computers the fonts show up rugged.

These are my font-declarations:

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: "Bitter";
    src: url('http://predict.lyon-forums.com/style/fonts/Bitter_Regular.otf'),
            url('http://predict.lyon-forums.com/style/fonts/Bitter_Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Oswald";
    src: url('http://predict.lyon-forums.com/style/fonts/Oswald_Regular.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Oswald Bold";
    src: url('http://predict.lyon-forums.com/style/fonts/Oswald_Bold.otf');
}
```

The website in question (still a homepage) is the following: http://predict.lyon-forums.com/

This is what the website (notice the top menu) should look like (as it displays on Chrome on my computer):

[image: Chrome]

On other computers running Chrome, the problem persists. This is what the website looks like on Opera:

[image: Opera]

The font is called 'Bitter,' and the problem persists in Firefox.

I would appreciate any help :)

EDIT: On another Stack Overflow question, I found written that fonts render from the PC if they already exist, however I deleted them from my computer.

Comment: My glasses must be out-of-date. Are the images different?

Comment: "I deleted them from my computer." -- WHAT? Why not just rename the fonts in your CSS?

Comment: @CaseyFalk, yep - they are. Try opening them up! Also, I'm crazy that way. I wanted to be 100% sure!

Comment: If you say so... http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/131/399/fry.PNG?1307468855

Comment: As a possible solution, I put the SVG first. It renders much better. Anyone can guide me on whether this is bad practice?

@Paulie_D I used that link, yes, but it didn't help me much.

Comment: Just get used to it, font's render differently in different browsers and on different systems. It's an unfortunate fact (that developers have to often try to communicate to outraged designers).

Answer (score 0):

It is because every browser has its own font rendering engine, they are all different, can be changed in later version, or difference OS.

Try to using in your css:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
```

If its Chrome, you can use [this](http://eligrey.com/blog/post/better-font-smoothing-in-google-chrome-on-windows) , but it may causes issues in others browsers.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help :/

Comment: We don't have much to do about it. Every browser and OS renders its own way. :/

Comment: Don't worry about it. Thanks all the same - I really appreciate it!